# AS: How to handle custom event in parent component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events

I defined a simple event class:

public class NewMoveEvent extends Event
{

```
public function NewMoveEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=true)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

}

Then in custom mxml component, I defined a button which triggers it:

```
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:ns1="ui.*" layout="absolute" width="682" height="412" title="Board">
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="newformevent", type="events.NewMoveEvent")]
</mx:Metadata>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import events.NewMoveEvent;
        import config.Config;


        private function addNewUIComponent(event:Event):void
        {
            var e:NewMoveEvent = new NewMoveEvent("newformevent");
            dispatchEvent(e);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<ns1:ChessBoard x="8" y="9" width="350" height="350" backgroundColor="0x99CCCC" moveId="0" name="chessboard" themeColor="#FFFFFF"/>
<mx:Button id="next" x="507" y="127" label="Next" click="addNewUIComponent(event)"/>
<ns1:PieceContainer x="363" y="10" width="292" height="51" items="{Config.piecesWhite}" id="white"/>
<ns1:PieceContainer x="362" y="69" width="292" height="51" items="{Config.piecesBlack}" id = "black"/>
<ns1:PasteBin x="363" y="306" width="292" height="53" backgroundColor="0x99CCCC" id="paste"/>
<mx:Button x="445" y="127" label="Save" name="save" enabled="false"/>
```

No from the main application file I want to set the event handler, to this event. 
I can easily do it from mxml

e.g.

But cant do it in actionscript (e.g. this code don't work):

```
        private function addNewUIContainer(event:Event):void
        {
            var newBoard:UIContainer = new UIContainer();
                newBoard.addEventListener(NewMoveEvent.NEWFORMEVENT, addNewUIContainer);
        }
```

Compiler gives me an error. Don't understand why.

### ERROR

Access of possibly undefined property NEWFORMEVENT through a reference with static type Class.

And yes, UIContainer is mxml class

---

The function addNewUiContainer is defined in main file (project.mxml)

Comment: can you copy-paste the error in there so we can get a better idea of what's going on? and UIContainer is that MXML class?  And where is that "addNewUIContainer" method defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have defined the `public static const NEWFORMEVENT:String = "newformevent";`

```
public class NewMoveEvent extends Event
{
    public static const NEWFORMEVENT:String = "newformevent";

    public function NewMoveEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=true)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

}
```

Was that it?